# Calculate the limit of the following sequence with root in denominator

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I solve this simple limit problem?

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{a}_{n} = \frac{2n}{\sqrt{n^2 + 3}}$$

I know the limit is 2. I saw a solution where the ratio is squared yielding

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{a}_{n} = \frac{4n^2}{n^2+3}$$

Taking the limit this would yield 4. Which is the true limit squared. So to get the true limit the the solution calculates the limit as $$\sqrt{4} = 2$$

Is this allowed? I mean generally the squaring of a ratio is not equivalent to the original ratio. What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that a limit w.r.t. $n$ cannot depend on $n$.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz what does this mean??

Comment: @CSquared It means that saying $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \frac{2n}{\sqrt{n^2 +3}}$ is actually nonsense. Instead, it should be $a_n = \frac{2n}{\sqrt{n^2 +3}}$ or at least $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n}{\sqrt{n^2 +3}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2n}{\sqrt{n^2 + 3}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2n}{n\sqrt{1 + \frac{3}{n^2}}}=2$$

Comment: Simple and elegant! Love it!

Answer (score 2):

You're right to be suspicious: this method does have a hole in it. Fortunately, it's not a difficult hole to plug.

It's always valid, when you have a sequence $x_n \to x$, to square the sequence, and conclude it tends to $x^2$. This comes from continuity of the square map $x \mapsto x^2$; because it's continuous, it preserves limits.

The same can be said of the square root map. If $x_n \to x$, where $x_n$ and $x$ are non-negative (i.e. in the domain of the square root map), then it is valid to say $\sqrt{x_n} \to \sqrt{x}$ by continuity.

In this case, we start with a sequence $x_n$, of unknown convergence, square it, then note that the limit of $x_n^2$ is $4$. We can then use the continuity of the square root to conclude that
$$\sqrt{x_n^2} \to \sqrt{4} = 2.$$
The problem is, $\sqrt{x_n^2} = |x_n|$, not necessarily $x_n$. If we knew nothing else about $x_n$, then we couldn't conclude that $x_n \to 2$, or even that $x_n$ converges. It could converge to $-2$, or it could oscillate between the two limit points.

Fortunately, it's really straight forward to show that $x_n \ge 0$ for all $n$ in *this particular case*, and so $|x_n| = x_n$ for all $n$. Thus $x_n = |x_n| \to 2$, by the above logic, so we have indeed shown $x_n \to 2$ as $n \to \infty$ (with that one extra observation).

Answer (score 2):

Note that your evaluating this limit at infinity, thus the + 3 can be neglected.
That will leave you with a term, that can be simplified and resulting in 2.
Now just use that fact that the limit of a constant is equals to the constant.

If you're unsure, try using techniques like L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Isn't L'Hopital's rule only for functions?

Comment: @Rubus Yes, but if you just pretend $n$ is a real number $x$ instead of an integer, l'Hopital's rule applies. Unfortunately, due to a quirk of this particular limit, the limit it produces will be of similar complexity to the original limit.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, squaring the 'ratio', usually would be called the general term or sequence, does not typically yield the same limit. However, since the squaring function and the square root functions are continuous, we can do this and still recover the correct answer. All this means is that $$\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^2$$ and $$\sqrt{\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{a_n}$$ for any convergent sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers.

Again, this method only works if the function is continuous.